# mysql_fetch_assoc only returns 1 result

Tags: php

`mysql_fetch_assoc` is only fetching one record (checked database side of things all good)
Php Code:

```
<?php 
$folder_id = $_GET['folder_id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery_photos WHERE folder_id = $folder_id");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0)
{
    echo '<h2>Sorry, you cannot change a folders photo cover if that folder has 
         no    photos in it<br /> <a href="gallery.albums.php?fder_id='
         .$folder_id.'">Back to the folder</a><h2>';
}
else
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        echo '<img src="gallery_photos/'.$row['photo_name'].'" width="200"';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the DB data.  Are you sure it should be returning multiple rows?

Comment: Did you try for example mysql_fetch_array with assoc ? By the way you have a curious sql injection vulnerability in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You're not closing the HTML IMG tag. Add the `/>` to your tag.

```
echo '<img src="gallery_photos/'.$row['photo_name'].'" width="200" />';
```

Comment: Ohh dear how did i not see that, i do that all the time, thanks for the quick response m8 ur a life saver ;)

Comment: Well, sometimes live saving is not that difficult. Take a hint from a fellow developer: this is the moment where you want to take a 30 minute walk. :)

Comment: And after that, do indent your code. Good aesthetics help you catch these things easier.

Comment: it is indented on my editor but not on here for some reason :/